# Django 1.6: Error on sending email

Tags: python, django, email

I'm trying to implement Forgot password and was testing if it sends emails from the python shell, but I get the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Here is the relevant code in settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'something@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'blahblah'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'somthing@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL =  'something@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are running python shell using the command `python`. So the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` variable is not available. Run your application specific python shell using

```
python manage.py shell
```

Read more about [manage.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-py-and-manage-py).

> manage.py sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE environment variable so that it points to your project’s settings.py file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and do anything in Django by just starting a Python shell. Always do `manage.py shell`.